# Synchronization With SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, synchronization, package

I want to Synchronize two databases in **SQLite** using **C#**

i want to find the package or any other method to Synchronize databases

i am using following **namespaces** but not find the package please help me.

```
using Devart.Data.Synchronization;
using Devart.Data.SQLite.Synchronization;
```

Comment: What is your exact definition of "synchronize databases"?

Comment: i want to find the package of                                    
 Devart.Data.Synchronization;
 Devart.Data.SQLite.Synchronization. namespaces

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.SQLite << This one?

Comment: no it's not working.

Comment: please visit this link [dotConnect for SQLite 5.11 Professional Trial]( https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/download.html)  and download then add the dll.